# HttpResponseRedirect Reverse not working Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect my page after submitting a like button to the same page but I keep getting a

```
NoReverseMatch at /score/like/2
```

Here is the urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('like/<int:pk>', LikeView, name='like_post'),
```

Here is the views

```
def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post-detail', args=[str(pk)])) <-----Error highlighting here
```

here is the templates

```
                        <form action="{% url 'score:like_post' post.pk %}" method='POST'>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                                <button type='submit' name='post_id' class= "btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="{{post.id}}"> Like </button>                            
                        </form>                        
                        <strong>{{post.total_liked}} Likes </strong>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the template your `urls.py` specify an `app_name`. You need to use that as prefix in the name of the view.

Furthermore you can make use of [**`redirect(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) which calls `reverse` and wraps the result in a `HttpResponseRedirect` (so it removes some  boilerplate):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    post.likes.add(request.user)
    return redirect('score:post-detail', pk=pk)
```